# Bubble sort logic, number of iterations

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I have the following code:

```
// C program for implementation of Bubble sort 
#include <stdio.h> 

void swap(int *xp, int *yp) 
{ 
    int temp = *xp; 
    *xp = *yp; 
    *yp = temp; 
} 

// A function to implement bubble sort 
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
   int i, j; 
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)       

       // Last i elements are already in place    
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)  
           if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) 
              swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]); 
} 

/* Function to print an array */
void printArray(int arr[], int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i=0; i < size; i++) 
        printf("%d ", arr[i]); 
    printf("n"); 
} 

// Driver program to test above functions 
int main() 
{ 
    int arr[] = {64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90}; 
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); 
    bubbleSort(arr, n); 
    printf("Sorted array: \n"); 
    printArray(arr, n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

The only part that makes me confused is where `i < n-1` in the first for loop and `J< n-i-1` in the inner for loop inside the BubbleSort function. Why arent they both set to `i <= n-1` and `J<=n-i-1`? For instance, the first iteration would be a total of n= 7, therefore it means it should go through the loop for 6 times in the outer loop and 6 times in the inner for loop. But, without the `<=` sign it would only be 5 iterations per loop. On the website, it has illustrated that both loops do go through 6 iterations however Im not sure how would that happen without the `<=`in place.

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Comment: C arrays with N entries have indexes 0 to N-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the use of `arr[j+1]`. Let's say your array has `n = 7`. Then when `i = 0` and `j = n - i - 1 = 6`, you would be accessing `arr[j+1] = arr[6 + 1] = arr[7]`. However, `arr` only had 7 elements to begin with, so index `7` is out of bounds since the indices begin at `0`, with `arr[6]` being the seventh element.

As for why it doesn't matter, the final element of the array is already swapped when comparing it to the next-to-last element. Or if the array only had 1 element, it is already sorted.

Comment: As a general comment, I think selection sort is better than bubble sort in every way, including ease of implementation/understanding (insertion sort is even better, but perhaps a bit harder to get right). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Comment: Thank you. But, how would the inner loop iterate 6 times if it is not set to <=. Without the <= it would only iterate 5 times which is not enough to go through all the numbers.

Comment: @user3314399 If `n = 7`, iterating from `i = 0` while `i < n - 1` iterates over the values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, which is six times because 0 is the first. And when at 5 the comparison `arr[5] > arr[6]` is made, which covers the seventh element at index 6.

Comment: I tried running the code and it prints an n at the end of the result. Any idea why? 11 12 22 25 34 64 90 n

Comment: @user3314399 Because you are printing `n` at the end with `printf("n");`?